# Yii2: cannot find route to a module console command

Tags: yii2, console, url-routing

When I trying to use a module based yii2 command, got an error that says it can't find the route to that command.

I got to ask and make sure that I do not miss any thing. I used to have this part of my code working. 
When one is setting up a controller for a module command, which files and configurations have to be made? Any one that can come up anything I have missed?

To set up module command, you need, as far I understand:

1. A controller file named commandnameController inside your module
2. A module file that extends BaseModule (or an inherited class) implements BootstrapInterface. In the bootstrap method make sure
   that $this->controllerNamespace is set to the namespace of the
   console command when application environment is console.
3. Add module to application modules array list, by doing it in your console config file or dynamically in some other place. In my case
   in a head-module that iterates through the extension list after
   valid modules. This is to be able to implement some kind of plugin
   extensions. If the module is listed in composer.json dependencies
   directly or indirectly. The module will be bootstrapped.

The extension is found, but I cannot run the command anymore. Is there anything more that has to be set in the code, that I have missed that probably have accidentally been deleted.

If anyone has an idea, please help me, I will appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you update with some code?

Comment: I finally manage to find the incorrect part of the code. It did ignore point 2, $this->controllerNamespace was not set to the console controller.
I will delete this post, since it will probably not be to any help for another person.

Comment: Pls dont delete it, I think this is very helpful. Pls put your answer in answers as well, and Ill upvote it